# Stopwatch in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, timer

I need a stopwatch that shows me the time in hh:mm:ss format

Comment: see [Tried to add a self-answered wiki-post, but just got downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601)

Answer (score 2):

This is a stopwatch that I made after researching a while and not finding the exact type I wanted. Hopefully this helps someone with the same issue. The time is showed on the screen in the hh:mm:ss format, if you need to change is in the getDisplayTimer() method

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

//timer
  public displayTimer;
  public isRunning: boolean = false;
  public startText = 'Start';
  public time;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.time = 0;
  }

 toggleTimer() {
    this.isRunning = !this.isRunning;
    this.stopwatch();
  }

 stopwatch() {
    timer(0, 1000).subscribe(ellapsedCycles => {
      if (this.isRunning) {
        this.time++;
        this.getDisplayTimer(this.time);
        this.startText = 'Pause';
      } else {
        this.startText = 'Start';
      }
    });
  }

getDisplayTimer(time: number) {
    var hours = '' + Math.floor(time / 3600);
    var minutes = '' + Math.floor(time % 3600 / 60);
    var seconds = '' + Math.floor(time % 3600 % 60);

    if (Number(hours) < 10) {
      hours = '0' + hours;
    } else {
      hours = '' + hours;
    }
    if (Number(minutes) < 10) {
      minutes = '0' + minutes;
    } else {
      minutes = '' + minutes;
    }
    if (Number(seconds) < 10) {
      seconds = '0' + seconds;
    } else {
      seconds = '' + seconds;
    }

    this.displayTimer = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }

 <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 m-b-30">
                    <section class="timer-counter-label">
                        <div *ngIf="displayTimer; else elseBlock">  {{displayTimer}} </div>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock> 00:00:00 </ng-template>
                    </section>
                    <section class="timer-button-container">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-light" (click)="toggleTimer()">
                            {{ startText }}
                        </button>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
```